# Quartz scheduler running job 48 hours instead of 24 hours on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler, sftp

I am using Quartz scheduler in my java web application which runs one job to export  file to sFTP server(MOVEit) and I set job to trigger particular time in a day but job is triggering one time in two days means instead of 24 hours it triggering at 48 hours

Used Cron expression to run at specific time: **0 0 09 * * ?**
**Using Tomcat and java 8 on Linux environment**

Comment: saying '09' instead of '9' is not very idiomatic, but I wouldn't expect it to make a difference. Your jobs isn't taking more than 24 hours by any chance?

Comment: Also, are you really sure that it isn't running? Precisely what evidence are you using to decide that?

Comment: Thanks for your observation, Job is having just few seconds of work and in my sFTP server I could not see any file at particular time

Comment: As said by @tgdavies you don't provide any evidence the job was not run at all. Is there any log when it is run, and an absence of log when it is not run ?

Comment: @mdimran perhaps the job is failing rather than not running